# How to add usernames and passwords to the file where chrome stores user credentials?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I have a lot of usernames and passwords that I want chrome to do auto fill when I go to the login page of the site to save time(I have around 1000 user ids and I might have to login with every user ids). I know that chrome stores the usernames and passwords in a file so can I store these information in that file? If it is possible then in which format should it be stored? If I should encrypt the credentials  before saving it on the file then can anybody point me to the encrypter that it uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, **this isn't possible**, not from a Chrome Extension nor a Chrome App, and not even manually, because these files are encrypted by Chrome. By the way, if you want, you can create an extension that uses a [content script](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fextensions%2Fcontent_scripts&ei=V1etVKefG8L_UrrygJAF&usg=AFQjCNHYrmPA7bJpKLmtkl6mFrRGdWOr-Q&sig2=xWK8o6vLYfVSX5NNC5fzIg&bvm=bv.83134100,d.d24) to inject the login details and automatically click the login button for you on certain pages.